# Getting horizontal overflow with scroll when width: 100vw is set on my container

Tags: html, css

So I created a basic grid for my site design and I used and make sure to add the viewport meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

The issue is that when I run the site in my browser it appears to have sliders on the bottom and right side like the content is bigger than the view area of my screen and the borders of the divs in the grid are out of the view. How to fix that? Here is my code:

```css
body{
    margin: 10px;
}
.container{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,fr);
    grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 1fr 100px;
    gap: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container div{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.header{
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
      <title>the title idk</title>
    </head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">Header</div>
      <div class="content-big"></div>
      <div class="content-small"></div>
      <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you set `width: 100vw;` on `.container` and also have `margin: 10px;` on `body`. So your website's width is actually `100vw + 20px` so it overflows.
A solution is to simply remove that `width: 100vw` from `.container`, as it takes all the available width by default.

```css
body{
    margin: 10px;
}
.container{
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,fr);
    grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 1fr 100px;
    gap: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container div{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.header{
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
      <title>the title idk</title>
    </head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">Header</div>
      <div class="content-big"></div>
      <div class="content-small"></div>
      <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```